# writing changed value from list to file, second iteration doesn't work, Python

Tags: python, file

The following function, part of a larger program, seeks to allow a user to "like" a film and store this value (by incrementing it) in the films text file. Oddly, it works ok in the first iteration (reads it into list, changes the value, writes it to file) but on the second time round, an error occurs.

The file is called "films.txt and the contents are:

```
    0,Genre,Title,Rating,Likes
    1,Sci-Fi,Out of the Silent Planet,PG,0
    2,Sci-Fi,Solaris,PG,0
    3,Sci-Fi,Star Trek,PG,0
    4,Sci-Fi,Cosmos,PG,0
    5,Drama,The English Patient,15,1
    6,Drama,Benhur,PG,0
    7,Drama,The Pursuit of Happiness,12,0
    8,Drama,The Thin Red Line,18,0
    9,Romance,When Harry met Sally,12,0
    10,Romance,You've got mail,12,0
    11,Romance,Last Tango in Paris,18,0
    12,Romance,Casablanca,12,0
```

The code for this specific function is as below: Note: the idnumber refers to the idnumber for each film. For instance the idnumber for StarTrek is 3.

```
def likeafilm(x,username):
#prompt the user to enter the ID number they require
   idnumber=int(input("To confirm, please enter the number of the film you wish to like:"))
   #create a list which stores and displays all the data in the films txt file
   with open("films.txt",mode="r", encoding="utf8") as f:
      allfilms=[]
      reader=csv.reader(f)
      for row in reader:
         allfilms.append([element.strip() for element in row])

         #print(allfilms)
      print("print the third film", allfilms[3])
      print("print the second film", allfilms[2])
      print("print the current film selected", allfilms[idnumber])
      print("print the like for current film", allfilms[idnumber][4])

      allfilms[idnumber][4]=str(int(allfilms[3][4])+1) #this succesfully increments the record in the runtime list by 1
      print(allfilms) #this confirms the update - this now needs to be written to file.

   with open("films.txt","w") as f:
      writer=csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerows(allfilms)

   print("******BACK TO VIEWING FILMS SELECTION***********")
   watchfilms(username)
```

On the first iteration, or first time I run the program, it works alright! The 1 is incremented (for the likes), and all is well. The error that occurs is as follows, on the second time round ....

```
    print("print the like for current film", allfilms[idnumber][4])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
def likeafilm(x,username):
#prompt the user to enter the ID number they require
   idnumber=int(input("To confirm, please enter the number of the film you wish to like:"))
   #create a list which stores and displays all the data in the films txt file
   with open("films.txt",mode="r", encoding="utf8") as f:
      allfilms=[]
      reader=csv.reader(f)
      for row in reader:
         allfilms.append([element.strip() for element in row])

         #print(allfilms)
      print("print the third film", allfilms[3])
      print("print the second film", allfilms[2])
      print("print the current film selected", allfilms[idnumber])
      print("print the like for current film", allfilms[idnumber][4])

      allfilms[idnumber][4]=str(int(allfilms[3][4])+1) #this succesfully increments the record in the runtime list by 1
      print(allfilms) #this confirms the update - this now needs to be written to file.

   with open("films.txt","w") as f:
      writer=csv.writer(f)
      #writer.writerows(allfilms)
      allfilms.append([element.strip() for element in row])
      writer.writerows(allfilms)

   print("******BACK TO VIEWING FILMS SELECTION***********")
   watchfilms(username)
```

As Apollo has suggested below, I can see what is happening (the error) but don't know how to fix it. It works on the first iteration because the file is correct (no spaces). On the SECOND iteration however, the file has been overwritten and it appears to have done something to the contents of the file. The second time around it comes up with this error:

```
    print("print the like for current film", allfilms[idnumber][4])
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried this for Film 5 (The English Patient - great film by the way), and while it updated it the first time round and the likes increment to "1", the second time, it does not.

I also tried changing the file writer to "wb" instead of "w", but the following error occured for that too:

```
writer.writerows(records)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: What error occurs ?

Comment: @Arman - I've just edited the original to include the error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea but I would break it into two functions, one to increment the film like and one for user interaction. Also, you tried to specify 'encoding', which is not a valid parameter, in your call to the built-in function open().

```
import csv

films_file = "films.txt"

def like_film(x):
    with open(films_file,mode="r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        records = [row for row in reader]
    for rec in records:
        if int(rec[0]) == x:
            rec[-1] = str(int(rec[-1]) + 1)
    with open("films.txt","wb") as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(records)

def user_like_film(username):
    x = int(input("Enter the ID of the film you wish to like: "))
    like_film(x)
    watchfilms(username)
```

Comment: -Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but it came up with the following error: I tried "liking" Film 5:  ERROR: line 283, in likeafilm
    if int(rec[0]) == x:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is the csv writer inserting blank lines in your output CSV file? if rec[0] doesn't exist, it suggests that the csv reader encountered an empty row in films.txt. If it is inserting empty rows, make sure you use open("films.txt","wb") instead of open("films.txt","w") before instantiating the writer so you don't have to worry about how line endings are handled.

Comment: I just tried it both ways ("wb" and "w"). While there is an extra carriage return entered in "w" mode the reader and writer still handle the lines without errors. If you post your updated code, I might have more suggestions.

Comment: I can see the problem: It works the first time perfectly. The second time round, the WRITING to the file adds a line or something, which messes it all up(I think). Second time round an index out of range error occurs (see edit and error message)

Comment: On changing it to "wb" btw, it throw the following error:    writer.writerows(records)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface - so that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

In Python 2, the file would need to be opened with 'wb', as you suggested, instead of 'w'.

I am however, using Python 3. In Python 3 the required syntax is slightly different. The file needs to be opened with an additional parameter, namely: newline='' instead.

An example below:

```
# Python 2
with open('filmsfile.txt', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

# Python 3
with open('filmsfile.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
```